# Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 create directory if not exists in python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

How to check whether the directory exists. if not create a directory

```
filesystem_client.create_directory("my_directory")
```

will create a directory, but i want to achieve something like this:

```
if not os.path.exists("my_directory"):
   filesystem_client.create_directory("my_directory")
```

Answer (score 0):

A directory will automatically be created if it does not exist, however, if you're referring to a file system/container then from my knowledge there does not seem to be a pythonic way of doing that, however, you can just wrap the code within a try except block, if it does not exist it will get caught in the except block and you can then create the file system/container.